# Craft4 stream_copy_to_stream(): Argument #2 ($to) must be of type resource, bool given

Tags: assets, craft4

As mentioned in the title, I'm not able to upload any files in Craft4.
I created a filesystem and a volume which is connected to the filesystem. In the assets-field settings I added the volume. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. For any help I would be grateful.
I'm using Craft v4.1.3

Comment: Is it local storage? Are you sure the volume has write permissions?

Comment: @mcoze Would you be able to elaborate more on your new settings? My base path is set to "@webroot/uploads" but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I put a bit more of explanation in the anwer above, hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must have looked at the screen for too long. The problem was that I didn't use relative path and url settings.
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/sites.html#step-6-check-your-asset-volumes-settings

Here is a bit more of clarification @samroberts707 asked for:
If your base path is set to `@webroot/uploads`in Crafts Filesystem Settings then the Base-Url should be set to `uploads`, at least that is what I did.

Comment: Besides setting the base path URL, need to ensure owner is set to daemon:daemon