# Upload Image in Craft CMS on Server

Tags: image, upload

When I upload image in server I get [image]:

```
stream_copy_to_stream(): Argument #2 ($to) must be of type resource, bool given
```

Comment: Hi @user13498! Is [this issue](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/39643/craft4-stream-copy-to-stream-argument-2-to-must-be-of-type-resource-bool) relevant? If not, could you detail what you’re uploading to and how it’s configured?

Answer (score 1):

Check the file permissions on your uploads directory. The apache/nginx user or group should have write permission.